# How do i setup Pyspark in Python 3 with spark-env.sh.template

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, pyspark

Because i have this issue in my ipython3 notebook, i guess i have to change "spark-env.sh.template" somehow.

Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.4, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark does not yet work with Python 3.If you wish to use the Python API you will also need a Python interpreter (version 2.6 or newer).

I had the same issue when running `IPYTHON=1 ./pyspark`.

Ok quick fix

Edit `vim pyspark` and change `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="ipython"` line to

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="ipython2"
```

That's it.

If you want to check where dose `ipython` points to,

Type `which ipython` in terminal and I bet that'll be

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/ipython
```

****UPDATED****

The latest version of spark works well with python 3. So this may not need with the latest version.

Just set the environment variable:

`export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3`

in case you want this change to be permanent add this line to pyspark script

Comment: Spark supports Python 3 now and at the time of the answer as well. See e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279783

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can specify the two separately, like so:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/anaconda/bin/ipython
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/opt/anaconda/bin/ipython
```

Based on this other question [Apache Spark: How to use pyspark with Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279783/apache-spark-how-to-use-pyspark-with-python-3).

Comment: what's the difference between PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON?