# Change Apache Livy's Python Version

Tags: python, apache-spark, hue

I have Apache Livy installed. Got this error when submit my code to Livy. How to change default Python Version in Apache Livy?

```
Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.5 than that in driver 2.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions

import sys
print(sys.version)
```

> {'id': 2, 'state': 'available', 'output': {'data': {'text/plain':
>   '2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56) \n[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red
>   Hat 4.4.7-11)]'}, 'status': 'ok', 'execution_count': 2}}

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940631/how-do-i-setup-pyspark-in-python-3-with-spark-env-sh-template

Comment: I have changed the PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON, still no helps.