# Change Python version Livy uses in an EMR cluster

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, livy

I am aware of [Change Apache Livy's Python Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289559/change-apache-livys-python-version) and [How do i setup Pyspark in Python 3 with spark-env.sh.template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940631/how-do-i-setup-pyspark-in-python-3-with-spark-env-sh-template).

I also have seen the [Livy documentation](https://livy.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#pyspark)

However, none of that works. Livy keeps using Python 2.7 ***no matter what***.

This is running Livy 0.6.0 on an EMR cluster.

- I have changed the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environment variable to `/usr/bin/python3` in the hadoop user, my user, the root, and ec2-user.  Logging into the EMR master node via `ssh` and running `pyspark` starts python3 as expected.  But, Livy keeps using python2.7.
- I added `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3` to the `/etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh` file.  Livy keeps using python2.7.
- I added `"spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON":"/usr/bin/python3"` and `"spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON":"/usr/bin/python3"` to the items listed below and in every case .  Livy keeps using python2.7.

  - sparkmagic `config.json` and `config_other_settings.json` files before starting a PySpark kernel Jupyter
  - Session Properties in the sparkmagic `%manage_spark` Jupyter widget. Livy keeps using python2.7.
  - `%%spark config` cell-magic before the line-magic `%spark add --session test --url http://X.X.X.X:8998 --auth None --language python`

**Note: This works without any issues in another EMR cluster running Livy 0.7.0**  I have gone over all of the settings on the other cluster and cannot find what is different.  I did not have to do any of this on the other cluster, Livy just used python3 by default.

How exactly do I get Livy to use python3 instead of python2?

Answer (score 1):

Finally just found an answer after posting.

I ran the following in a PySpark kernel Jupyter session cell before running any code to start the PySpark session on the remote EMR cluster via Livy.

```
%%configure -f
{ "conf":{
          "spark.pyspark.python": "python3"
         }
}
```

Simply adding `"spark.pyspark.python": "python3"`  to the .sparkmagic `config.json` or `config_other_settings.json` also worked.

Confusing that this does not match the official Livy documentation.