# How to run Spark with Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda3, Ubuntu)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

i did download anaconda3, spark1.6.1, java, git etc...

and i set up environment like this

```
$ nano .bashrc
export PATH="/home/moon/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/src/scala/scala-2.12.1
export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export SPARK_PATH=~/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6
export PATH=$SPARK_PATH/bin:$PATH    

export ANACONDA_ROOT=/usr/home/moon/anaconda3
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=$ANACONDA_ROOT/bin/python3

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"

$. .bashrc

$cd spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6
$bin/pyspark
```

then i can connect jupyter notebook (python3)
**But i can`t run spark ex) sc , sc.textFile**

How can i integrate spark and jupyter

Comment: https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree#install

Answer (score 2):

Please add below.

```
 PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"    ./bin/pyspark
```

Also check below:
[Apache Spark: How to use pyspark with Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279783/apache-spark-how-to-use-pyspark-with-python-3)

**I faced some compatibility issue with anaconda python 3 and i switched to anaconda python 2.7**